# Sorting and Page Indexing GridView. I have hit a wall

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging

I have a gridview that is in an updatepanel. The sort works fine when you click the column headers but if I go to the next page, the sort is lost. I will provide the code below and if ANYONE out there has an idea on how to get out of this mess, please help!

The ShowGrid() function is called in the Page_Load. I am guessing the problem lies with recalling ShowGrid() in the paging function.

```
 //Show Grid based on argument type
protected void ShowGrid(string arg)
{
    //dataset to hold email addresses
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        //open connection with new connection string            
        conn.Open();

        String selectString = String.Format("SELECT * FROM hr_OnlineJobApp"
                     + " WHERE adminCategory='" + adminCategory + "'"
                     + "AND departmentApplyingFor LIKE '" + dept + "' ORDER BY {0} {1}", ViewState["sortExp"], ViewState["sortOrder"]);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, conn);


        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        //bind to gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["pageIndex"]);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
 /**********************************************
 * Paging functionality 
 * *******************************************/
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //reshow Grid with current type
    adminCategory = GridView1.DataKeys[0]["adminCategory"].ToString();
    ViewState["pageIndex"] = e.NewPageIndex.ToString();
    ShowGrid(adminCategory);
}

/**********************************************
 * Sorting functionality 
 * *******************************************/
protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExp = e.SortExpression;
    ViewState["sortExp"] = sortExp;
    string sortDir = (string)ViewState["sortOrder"];

    //Changes the sortDir
    if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "desc")
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "asc";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["sortOrder"] = "desc";
    }

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM hr_OnlineJobApp"
                     + " WHERE adminCategory='" + adminCategory + "'"
                     + "AND departmentApplyingFor LIKE '" + dept + "' ORDER BY " + sortExp + " " + sortDir;


        SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);


        GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `PageIndex` to 0 in `Showgrid`:

```
GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
```

Therefore you're overwriting the new value from  `PageIndexChanging`

```
GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

So you just don't need to set the PageIndex in ShowGrid to fix the issue.

Another possible reason for the issue:

Maybe you're databinding the GridView on every postback from `Page_Load`. You should do that only at the first time. Use the `Page.IsPostBack` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
       ShowGrid();
}
```

**Last but not least**: you are sorting only if the user clicks on the header in `gridView_Sorting`. You should apply the `ORDER BY` also in `ShowGrid` or use only one method to databind your GridView. But you're always ordering by `date desc` there.

You should not use a DataView to apply the sort, instead you should use the `ORDER BY` in the sql at the first place.

```
String sql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM hr_OnlineJobApp"
                         + " WHERE adminCategory='"+adminCategory+"'"
                         + " ORDER BY {0} {1}", sortExp, sortDir); 
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

Comment: Woops, that was from some testing I was doing. That code is not normally in the code. I removed it and it still loses the sort once the page index changes. Any other suggestions? I just can't seem to grasp why it would be losing its sort.

Comment: I am calling ShowGrid() in the Page_Load just like that already. ShowGrid() is only called if !IsPostBack

Comment: @user1054156: You are not ordering(always by `date`) in `ShowGrid`, edited my answer.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, this still did not resolve my problem. I have been at this since Friday and still can't figure it out. Is the new above code correct, and if so...Any more suggestions?

Comment: @user1054156: Only you can tell us if it's working now. Is the ViewState variable set? You should use a property to store the variable. The property variable can lead to the ViewState variables and should set them if they are not set(f.e. `DATE DESC`). And don't store the `PageIndex` in ViewState. The GridView already stores it.

Comment: No it is not working. I have set ViewState["sortExp"] and ViewState["sortOrder"] in the Page_Load to "date" and "desc". The sort functionality in the original question shows how I update them. Thank you for your time btw.

Comment: Ah! I got it to work. I was setting the ViewState variables outside of the if(!IsPostBack) of the Page_Load. Doh! Thank you again, so much.

Comment: That's the advantage of a property. You don't need to take care of setting the ViewState variables. It will be set automatically the first time the getter is called:`if(ViewState["sortExp"]==null)ViewState["sortExp"]="date"; return (String)ViewState["sortExp"]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you set GridView1.PageIndex = 0 in ShowGrid() function and then call that function on Page_Load event.So, on every postback, page index is set to 0 which create problem. You should remove that line to resolve te issue.

Comment: I apologize but that line of code should not have been in there. I used it for testing. The code has been updated but it sill does not hold the sort once the page index is changed.